# How Can I use functions in SpringBoard-Class.h?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

In SpringBoard-Class.h I found the functions such as these:

```
-(void)_powerDownNow;
-(void)_rebootNow;
-(void)reboot;
-(void)powerDown;
```

I am trying to use them. My iPhone is jailbroken.

I use `[[[SpringBoard alloc] init] reboot]`, but the compiling result is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
>       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SpringBoard", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RootViewController.mm.o
>       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
>       collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.

Comment: Seems to me that SprintBoard library is not being compiled. Check your build params in the project settings. Make sure it exists in your target.

Comment: I think you missed any `framework` which it need ...

Comment: @ Paul Peelen in fact I use TheOs to develop a jailbreak app?do you have any idea of that??

Comment: @Vakul Saini in fact,you can find a truth that springboard class is not a framework,it is a app type of file. meanwhile,i find springboard services is a framework.but it exists in the private framework document.um~~ can you go on helping me ??

Comment: Sorry bro no idea about springboard .. but if would know i would surely let you know .... :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you are developing a tweak which hooks into SpringBoard.
If you don't have the headers present, you can always use

```
[objc_getClass("SpringBoard") sharedApplication] methodToUse];
```

This will produce a warning... but it will be fine.

You can't call SpringBoard's methods from an app, because SpringBoard is not a library you can link to. It is an app itself.